# Xubuntu change/remap `home` key to backspace

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, remapping

I want to remap the `home` key to do the same as the backspace. I have looked through [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions), but couldn't find any references to the home key in the file it talks about, but maybe I am looking in the wrong place in the file?

Comment: what is the environment of use ? what xubuntu version are you actually using?

Answer (score 0):

As you see from [the guide you referred to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions), customizing the keyboard layout is complicated.

You can find the symbolic name of a key as follows

1. Run `xev -event keyboard | grep keycode`. Hit the key and note the keycode.
2. You also find the current keysym in the output
3. Find the evdev scancode  matching the keycode you found in the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`.

Then you can locate the evdev scancode of the key you want to change in your keyboard layout file.